# Best data access method in .NET 2.0

Tags: .net, sql, dao

When developing with .NET 3.5 I naturally use LINQ for data access.

But for .NET 2.0 projects, what data access model is the best one to use? I tend to use TableAdapters mainly, but sometimes also write my own SQL depending on the situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.org)? I haven't used it much myself, but my experience with its Java cousin was very positive.

There are other alternatives such as [LLBLGen](http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx) as well.

It would be very hard to recommend an overall "best" solution without knowing more about the problem though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't know Hibernate had a .NET port, I've also had very good experiences with Hibernate with Java so I will defiantly give that a look.

Answer (score 2):

[CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) is another good tool from what I've heard.

There's no such thing as the *best* DAL, only the *best* for the current solution.

We used an in-house one for many years which wasn't too bad but ultimately unmaintainable vs commercial products.

Answer (score 1):

For an MVC style ASP .Net 2.0 application you can use Castle project and ActiveRecord for data access. ActiveRecord can be used separately.

**Active Record**
"The enterprise data mapping pattern implemented using NHibernate"
http://www.castleproject.org/

Comment: I was less than impressed with ActiveRecord when I was investigating it the other week. I'm too use to having a code-gen than having to hand-code my classes. Or is there a code gen for it?